# Very strange behaviour related to htaccess and custom posts and custom posts substrings (BUG?)

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I have a custom post whose name is "babysitter".

I wrote this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^babysitter/?$ /index.php/some-page/ [QSA,L]
```

In layman terms, if url matches **hostname.com/babysitter** or **hostname.com/babysitter/** go to **hostname.com/index.php/some-page**.
The strange behaviour I get is that this doesn't work (I mean RewriteRule is not matched) and I get a 404 error but even stranger is that this doesn't work even for strings starting with the first letters of **babysitter** and are substrings of it for example:
**baby** or **bab** or **babys**.
Instead it works if I write **ababy** or everything else which doesn't begin with custom post name:

```
RewriteRule ^ababysitter/?$ /index.php/some-page/ [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^ababy/?$ /index.php/some-page/ [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ /index.php/some-page/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^cba/?$ /index.php/some-page/ [QSA,L]
```

For all the rules just above urls:
hostname.com/ababysitter
hostname.com/ababy
hostname.com/abc
hostname.com/cba
bring me to **hostname.com/index.php/some-page** which is what I want.

IS THIS A BUG IN WORDPRESS?

Basically what I am trying to achieve is that, if "babysitter" is a custom post:
hostname.it/babysitter gives me a page;
hostname.it/babysitter/4567 gives me the post page;

Comment: Is your rule above or below WordPress’ in your htaccess?

Comment: It's inside it. Inside #BEGIN Wordpress #END Wordpress

Comment: the code inside these tags will be erased on the next flush. then you have to put your code outside. And put it before then it applies before wordpress ones.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. I completely removed wordpress stuff from htaccess and wrote just my directives. Nothing changed.